# Table cell's :hover attribute doesn't change background color

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code in my CSS file:

```
table .pc {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table .pc td {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

table .pc td,
table .pc th {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

table .pc td:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table .pc th {
    background-color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And I have the following HTML table:

```
<table class="pc">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>229</th>
            <th>230</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold center">
            <th>229</th>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(0,255,40);">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold center">
            <th>230</th>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(0,255,40);">0</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(242,12,40);">95</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that if I move my mouse over the cell's which doesn't have any inline styling it works properly and the default background color (white) will change to black, but when I move over a cell which has a background-color set inline, it does not do anything. (It only changes the color of the text to be white).

The cells' rgb code is generated in PHP based on the value they have inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inline styles have highest preference, and hence it wont work unless you use `!important` for `:hover`

```
table.pc td:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important; /* Add important over here */
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You also have a space between

<s>`table .pc`</s> for all your selectors which is incorrect, it should be `table.pc`

Because when you have a space between `table .pc`, it looks for an element with a `class` of `pc` nested inside your `table` element, which is not the case here.

So when you get rid of the space and make it `table.pc` it will look for `table` element with a `class` name of `pc`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuAh8/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, `!important` what I was looking for. Also thanks for the correction with `table.pc`, it works now.
Anyway, can you please tell me why was it working with table .pc before? (I have other tables also with similar class syntax and it was working perfectly before also)

Comment: @zdtorok No, I don't think it will work unless you have a nested table inside a table with a `class` of `.pc` :)

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles have a higher precedence than your CSS class declarations.

You can use the !important keyword in your CSS to have it override inline styles.

```
table .pc td:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avohi) to td add class
**HTML**

```
<table class="pc">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>229</th>
            <th>230</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold center">
            <th>229</th>
            <td></td>
            <td class="green">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold center">
            <th>230</th>
            <td class="green">0</td>
            <td class="red">95</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table .pc {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table .pc td {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

table .pc td,
table .pc th {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.green {
  background-color: rgb(0,255,40);
}
.red {
  background-color: rgb(242,12,40);
}
td:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table .pc th {
    background-color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned that the colors are generated dynamically in the range 0-100 and it's not a good way to write the color codes for every value from 0 to 100.

Comment: your selectors which is incorrect, it should be table.pc

Answer (score 0):

To get Table element with class name "pc" , you need write table.pc

```
table.pc td:hover {
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please refer the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/anu1718/v5E72/